# Sqoop Incremental Import Lastmodified fails with Error :Could not get current time from database

Tags: sql, hive, db2, sqoop

I'm trying to import a table from DB2 database using Sqoop incremental lastmodified. The table has a column of Timestamp type which is the check column im using.  I wanted to import all the whole table first and then subsequently import any latest modification, hence I set my last-value to 0. Below is the command:

NOTE: Some values in the updateTS column is "1/1/0001 12:00:00"

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:db2*****************" --username **** --password ***** --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --table my_table --m 20 --split-by col1 --target-dir /user/employ/sqoop_dir --check-column updateTS --incremental lastmodified --last-value 0
```

When I execute the above command,I get the following error

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);<INTEGER>, DRIVER=4.17.29
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:747)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.c(wo.java:2771)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.d(wo.java:2759)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:2192)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:2168)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.h(ab.java:136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.o.a(o.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.i(tb.java:145)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.kb(wo.java:2161)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:3258)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:697)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.executeQuery(wo.java:676)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getCurrentDbTimestamp(SqlManager.java:986)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:346)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:525)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:633)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:242)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:251)
20/09/16 23:52:02 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Chained exception 1:
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, 
SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=4.17.29
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:752)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.c(wo.java:2771)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:2219)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.o(ab.java:908)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.j(ab.java:267)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.d(ab.java:55)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.o.c(o.java:44)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.j(tb.java:157)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.mb(wo.java:2214)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:3261)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.a(wo.java:697)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.executeQuery(wo.java:676)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getCurrentDbTimestamp(SqlManager.java:986)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:346)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:525)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:633)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:242)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:251) 
 20/09/16 23:52:02 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Could not get current 
  time from database
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:348)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:525)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:633)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:242)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:251)
```

Also if I simply import without incremental lastmodified condition, the import was successful.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:db2*****************" --username **** --password ***** --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --table my_table --m 20 --split-by col1 --target-dir /user/employ/sqoop_dir
```

However, the updateTS column which was in format 20/22/2002 is now converted to epoch timestamp.

How do I resolve these two issues?

Comment: Apparently, the SQL statement generated by Sqoop, has invalid syntax. Print it out and you will see what's wrong.

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks for your reply. However, all that were generated was what I displayed in the error message above. I could not see to figure out why it could not get current time from database. Any idea?